# Homework: Bayesian Data Analysis: Priors on both binomial parameters

Tags: self-study, bayesian, binomial-distribution

The following is a problem from *Bayesian Data Analysis 2nd ed*, p. 97. Andrew Gelman has not included its solution in the guide on his website and it has been driving me crazy all day. Literally all day.

For some data $y$, modeled as a binomial distribution with population $N$ and probability $\theta$ parameters, both of which are unknown. The problem sets up the question with this information:
(1) Setting a prior on $N$ is difficult, as it only takes on positive natural numbers, so it is treated as $\Pr(N|\mu) = Poisson(\mu)$, where $\mu$ is unknown. 
(2) To define the prior on $(N, \theta)$, we have $\lambda=\mu\theta$. (The logic here is that it may be easier to formulate a prior considering the unconditional expectation of the observations, rather than the mean of the unobserved $N$.)
(3) A potential noninformative prior is $p(\lambda, \theta) \varpropto 1/\lambda$.

The part of the problem that I am hung up on is how to transform the variables and determine $p(N, \theta)$.

The approach that I have attempted is to write $p(N,\theta|\lambda)p(\lambda, \theta)$, and eliminate the unwanted $\lambda$ via integration, that is $p(N,\theta)=\int_0^\infty C\mu^N/(exp(\mu)\lambda N!)d\lambda$, and substituting out $\mu$ with the relation $\mu=\lambda/\theta$. This approach reduces to $p(N,\theta)=C/(N+1)$, where $C$ is the constant of proportionality introduced from (3).

This result concerns me, because it implies that the joint probability of some values of $\theta$ and $N$ only depends on $N$, and not on $\theta$. Furthermore, some vague bells are ringing from my quite decrepit multivariable calculus, attempting to remind me about Jacobians and coordinate transformations, but I am uncertain that this integration approach is even appropriate.

I appreciate your help and insight.

Comment: In this case, why not email Andrew? He might like to redress the omission.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did all of the questions from the first four chapters six years ago. Here's what I have:

$p(\mu,\theta)\propto\left|\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial \mu}\right|p(\lambda,\theta)=\mu^{-1}.$

So

$\begin{array}{lrl}p\left(N,\theta\right) & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}p\left(\mu,N,\theta\right)\mathrm{d}\mu\\ & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}p\left(\mu,\theta\right)\Pr\left(N\,|\,\mu\right)\mathrm{d}\mu\\ & \propto & \int_{0}^{\infty}\mu^{-1}\left(\frac{\mu^{N}}{N!}e^{-\mu}\right)\mathrm{d}\mu\\ & = & \frac{\left(N-1\right)!}{N!}=N^{-1}\end{array}$

You don't need to be worried that $p(N,\theta)$ doesn't depend on $\theta$. This just means that the prior for $\theta$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, which is cool for a Bernoulli parameter.