# estimate a binomial parameters (n and p) from a distribution sample

Tags: python, binomial-distribution, estimators

I have found this function `def find_np(data):` that try to estimate p,n out of a binomial distribution sample:

```python
import numpy as np
def find_np(data):
    Expectation = sum(data)/len(data)
    Variance = sum([(Xi - Expectation) ** 2 for Xi in data]) / len(data)
    p = 1 - Variance / Expectation
    n = round(Expectation / p)
    p = Expectation / self.n
    print("estimated p->{}, n->{}".format(p, n))

data = np.random.binomial(50, 0.6, 100).tolist()
find_np(data)
```

I don't understand the code approach to estimate the parameters:

1. What's the mathematical Demonstration of:

> p = 1 - Variance / Expectation

2. Any Documentation resource of the code approach ?

Comment: In many experiments involving binomial data, $n$ is known and success probability $p$ is estimated by $\hat p = x/n,$ where $x$ is the observed number of successes. Various tests about and confidence intervals for $p$ are widely discussed in elementary and intermediate statistics texts. However, using binomial data to estimate an unknown number $n$ of trials is a more difficult and less often encountered problem. Can you clarify your purpose and what data you (expect to) have? // For me at least, a bit of undocumented code is not an adequate description of your problem.

Comment: For the problem of estimating the binomial $n$, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123367/estimating-parameters-for-a-binomial/123748#123748

Answer (score 2):

1. A binomial distribution with probability of success $p$ and number of trials $n$ has expectation $\mu = np$ and variance $\sigma^2 = np(1-p)$. One can [derive these facts easily](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Variance_of_Binomial_Distribution), or look them up in a standard reference.

   Given the mean $\mu$ and the variance ${\sigma}^2$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
p &= 1 - \sigma^2 / \mu  \\
&= 1 - \frac{np(1-p)}{np} \\
&= 1 - (1 -p)\\
&= p
\end{align}$$
The code uses the estimate $\hat{p}$ and the estimated expectation to estimate $\hat{n}=\mu / \hat{p}$ (rounding to the nearest integer).

2. The code uses a [method-of-moments](/questions/tagged/method-of-moments) estimator for $p,n$, because it assumes that the sample moments (mean, expectation) equal the moments of the true distribution. The MME isn't the only one available; see also:

   - [Homework: Bayesian Data Analysis: Priors on both binomial parameters](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52873/)
   - [Estimating parameters for a binomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123367) in particular [the discussion to this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16871/22311) which describes the deficiencies of the technique used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $n=25$ and observed number of successes
$x = 15,$ then you can test $H_0: p=0.5$ against $H_a: p\ne 0.5$ at the 5% level and you can
find a 95% confidence interval for $p.$

In R, the procedure `binom.test` provides both the
P-value of the test and a 95% confidence interval.
Specifically, the P-value $0.4244 > 0.05 = 5\%$
indicates that the observed $\hat p = x/n = 0.6$
is not significantly different from $p_0 = 0.5$ at the 5% level. Accordingly, the 95% CI $(0.387, 0.789)$ contains $p_0 = 0.5.$

```
binom.test(15, 25, p=.5)

        Exact binomial test

data:  15 and 25
number of successes = 15, number of trials = 25, 
 p-value = 0.4244
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3866535 0.7887452
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                   0.6
```

By contrast, if you had more trials, say $n = 100$ with $x = 62$ successes, then you
could use an approximate normal test and confidence interval. [The chi-squared statistic shown in the printout below is the square of a normal test statistic.]
In this case, the null hypothesis $H_0: p = 0.05$ is rejected at the 2% level (thus also at the 5% level) in favor of the
alternative $H_a: p\ne 0.5$ and a 95% confidence
interval for $p$ is $(0.522, 0.709).$

```
prop.test(62, 100, p=.5, cor=F)

        1-sample proportions test 
        without continuity correction

data:  62 out of 100, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 5.76, df = 1, 
 p-value = 0.0164        # aprx P-val
alternative hypothesis: 
 true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5220976 0.7090240     # aprx 95% CI
sample estimates:
   p 
0.62
```

*Notes:* (1) In the second example, `binom.test` is still valid (as shown below). However, in elementary statistics books, you may find more
refences to approximate normal tests and CIs.

```
binom.test(62, 100, p=.5)$p.val
[1] 0.02097874          # exact P-value
binom.test(62, 100, p=.5)$conf.int
[1] 0.5174607 0.7152325 # exact 95% CI
attr(,"conf.level") 
[1] 0.95
```

In R, notation with `$` permits showing just
part of the output.

(2) @Sycorax (+1) has shown the $\hat p = x/n$ is the method-of-moments estimator (MME) of $p.$

In addition. $\hat p = x/n$ is the maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) of $p.$

You can find the MLE by finding the value $p$ that maximizes the binomial likelihood
function, which is the binomial PDF viewed
as a function of $p$ for known $x.$

The
maximum can be found by the usual methods
of calculus. Below is a graph of a numerical solution,
in which a 'grid search' is used to find
`p` for which `like` is maximized. For $n=100, x = 62,$ the MLE is $\hat p = x/n = 0.62.$

```
p= seq(.1, .99, by = .001)
like = dbinom(62, 100, p)
mle = p[like==max(like)];  mle
[1] 0.62
```

The following plot illustrates the likelihood function and its maximum.

```
hdr = "Likelihood Function Showing LME"
plot(p, like, type="l", lwd=2,
  ylab="Likelihood", xlab="x", main=hdr) 
 abline(v = mle, col="red")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
```

[image]

(3) Estimation of $n$ is not discussed in
this answer. Of course. if you have the data, then you can count the observations to find $n$ exactly for that sample. The difficult problem is to estimate $n$ more generally.
Perhaps see [this Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/estimator-for-a-binomial-distribution) and Google `estimate binomial sample size` for other references. including [this preprint](https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/%7Eboos/library/mimeo.archive/ISMS__1539.pdf)
and its References.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: My answer shows point and interval estimates of parameter $p.$  Your Answer (+1) discusses the MME of $p.$ I have added a note to my answer to illustrate the MLE of $p.$ I do not discuss the more difficult task of using data to estimate $n.$

Comment: I agree that this answer provides a (thorough!) description of the MLE for binomial $p$, but it doesn't seem to describe what OP's code is doing, or answer either of their enumerated questions.